# SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a list, somewhat similar to the one below.

> lines = ['This is line 1',
>        'This is another line',
>        'This is the third line. Line 03.']

When I run the `return` statement to process for the `len` of the line,

```
for line in lines:
    return(len(line))
```

generates the following error:

> File "", line 2
>           return(len(line))
>           ^
>       SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

I can however `print` the lengths of the lines,

```
for line in lines:
    print(len(line))
```

Result:

> 14 
>   20 
>   32

How exactly is the `return` statement outside function in this instance?

Edit:
Here is what it looks like in my Notebook.
[image: http://imgur.com/w4EzlrH]

Comment: where exactly have you placed that `for` loop that contains the `return`?It's either top level or you're not showing us. The `SyntaxError` is pretty descriptive, it *must* be in a function.

Answer (score 2):

Your indention might be inconsistent. Use four spaces per indention level as recommended by PEP-8. Secondly, it should be inside a function. Thirdly, your return statement won't return length of all the items as you want.

Answer (score 2):

The return function is used to pass a value back to where a certain function is called. The way I see it, you're essentially trying to overwrite the return value. You should use it in a function that does something and returns the value back. Your loop and return statement don't appear to be in a function.

In example below I take each item in the list, pass it into the check_len function, which obviously checks length of the item and returns it. Then, the length of each item in the list is printed.

Example:

```
lines = ['This is line 1',
'This is another line',
'This is the third line. Line 03.']

def check_len(i):
    return len(i)

for line in lines:
    print(check_len(line))
```